# How to select every element in an element list

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm a beginner programmer and I am trying to select every element in a class array to style them. I have tried using the generic selector `*` but this has not worked and I have not found a suitable solution.  eg.

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName;

link[*].style.color = "#eee";
```

Comment: Only if you could search, you wouldn't have posted this question here. Please follow [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Comment: Please do not point to W3Schools. Try MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

> [*document.getElementsByClassName*] returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

You need to specify what class to select, and then you'd have to iterate over each element in the returned array.

Suppose you have this HTML:

```
<p class="foo">Hello</p>
<p class="foo">World</p>
```

Then you'd need something like this in JavaScript:

```
var foo_items = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for(var i = 0; i < foo_items.length; i++) {
    foo_items[i].style.color = "#eee";
}
```

Of course, if you're using jQuery, this could be simplified to

```js
$(".foo").css("color", "#eee")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your browser console.

```
function getAllLinks() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('a')
}
var links = getAllLinks()
function colorElements(elements, value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
}
colorElements(links, 'red')
```

Code above should fetch all the links on the page and color them red.

Now with better ES6+

```
// this code requires links from the code above
var allLinks = Array.from(links)
allLinks.forEach(link => link.style.color = 'green')
```

Code above should take all the links on the page and color them green.

Advice: Do not touch browser or users anchor colors for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery loop or javascript loop. In jquery use $.each loop to parse through the loop elements and apply style to each element. I have added a sample code here using javascript and jQuery.

> jQuery implementation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="itemclass">Element 1.</p>

<p class="itemclass">Element 2.</p>

<p class="itemclass">Element 3.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemclass");
    $.each(items, function(index, item){
 item.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> Javascript Implementation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p class="itemclass">Element 1.</p>

<p class="itemclass">Element 2.</p>

<p class="itemclass">Element 3.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemclass");
 var loopVar = 0;
 var loopLength = items.length;
        for(loopVar = 0; loopVar < loopLength; loopVar++){
     items[loopVar].style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```